# Converting a 4-20mA 24V signal to 0-5V?

Tags: sensor, current-sensing, 4-20ma

How do I convert a 4-20mA 24V signal to a 0-5V signal, suitable for A-D conversion with a 5V microprocessor?  Can this be done while isolating the 24V from the 5V output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a 250 ohm resistor and remove the offset digitally.

To get an isolated input might be done by creating an isolated supply and digitizing the signal, then transferring it over an isolation barrier digitally. There are other approaches, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a voltage divider using two resistors R1 and R2, ensuring that the Thevenin resistance R1 // R2 is much lower than the input resistance of your ADC.

For isolation you can for exemple use an optocoupler, then the output of your voltage divider will feed the  input of your optocoupler and hence you have to ensure this time that R1 // R2 is much lower than the input resistance of your optocoupler circuit.